# Interpolation algorithm all values 255 -MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation, nearest-neighbor

I trying to create my own nearest neighbor interpolation algorithm in Matlab to enlarge an image of 556×612 to 1668×1836.

This is homework!!!

I have attempted this already but encounter the error where the values inside M gets (not all but most) transformed to 255 (White Space), and I cannot get my head around why. Any help would be appreciated! The picture is a picture of a zebra.

[image]

[image: Image after interpolation]

```
    %Take in image and convert to greyscale
I = imread('Zebra.jpg');
Igray = rgb2gray(I);

% Step-3: Resize the image to enlarged 1668x1836 by interpolation
% Step-3(a) : Using nearest neighbour
%First we will need to work out the dimension of the image
[j , k] = size(Igray);
%Now we need to set the size of the image we want
NewX = 1836;
NewY = 1668;
% Work out ratio of old to new
ScaleX = NewX./(j-1);
ScaleY = NewY./(k-1);

%Image Buffer
M = zeros(NewX, NewY);
%Create output image
for count1 = 1:NewX
    for count2 = 1:NewY
        M(count1,count2) = Igray(1+round(count1./ScaleX),1+round(count2./ScaleY));
    end
end
%Show Images
imshow(M);
title('Scaled Image NN');
```

Comment: Oh, I cannot use any inbuilt matlab functions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `imshow(M,[])`. You created `M` without specifying type, which makes it `double`. `double` images are [0-1], so `imshow` by default makes white everything with higher value than 1.

Alternatively, create `M` to be `uint8` as the original image

```
M = zeros(NewX, NewY,'uint8');
```

even better code would be:

```
M = zeros(NewX, NewY,class(Igray));
```